# Access Denied trying to access SharePoint 2013 REST API, User Profile endpoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, core-api

I am building a Provider Hosted App for SharePoint 2013 in PHP.  I have been successfully able to generate an access token for my user, and remotely access an api for showing all the lists.  (_api/web/lists).

However, I seem to be unable to access: https://mysharepointsite.com/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties

I get the message:
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

I am sending in the following HTTP headers which work for showing the lists, just not the user profile:

```
 $http_headers = array( 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
                    'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose'     );
```

The app permissions I am asking for are:

- News Feed (Social) : write
- User Profiles (Social) : read
- Tenant : Read
- Core (Social) : Read

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your app permissions set to read? in your app manifest

Comment: yes. Here is the xml output:
`<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Read" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/microfeed" Right="Write" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/core" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>`

Comment: Hi Graham, can you show a piece of code - how you've received a `token`? Which libraries were used? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the answer... but I found a different API endpoint that gave me enough information. I am still not sure if this is the best way to go, so any direction would be really helpful!

I used https://mysharepointsite.com/_api/Web/CurrentUser